# Undefined property: Login_Controller::$user

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why do I get this error? I Already Load database in libraries too,
but it's giving error

> Undefined property: Login_Controller::$user

I'm stuck for making login validation
[This Is The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRodf.png)

This is my autoload

```
$autoload['model'] = array();

$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','form_validation');
```

this is my Login_Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {        
        parent::__construct();
    }

     public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    function verify()
    {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $check = $this->user->validate();
        //$this->load->library('database');
        if($check)
        {
            $this->load->view('admin/main');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
            $message = "Username and/or Password incorrect.\\nTry again.";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }

    }
}
```

And This Is My Model

```
class User_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function __construct() {        
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function validate()
    {
        $array['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
        $array['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->db->get_where('user',$array)->result();
    }

}
```

Thanks For The Help

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code and error messages, so make an edit with the complete error message. I don't see any `$user` in your code example? Please update with Line17

Comment: Sorry, Line 17 is `$check = $this->user->validate();`

Comment: so that call from the model

Comment: i'm already fix it but can't login

Comment: $this->User_model->validate(); and make sure the model is User_model.php, Need to be capialized first letter

Comment: does the error go away if using `$this->User_model->validate();`instead of `$this->model->validate();` ?

Comment: if you are using $this->model->validate() then above line should be $this->load->model('user_model', 'model'); and it will not make any effect with current code.The error happens is that you are not returning anything from your model validate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change this line

```
$check = $this->user->validate();
```

to

```
$check = $this->user_model->validate();
```

2. Update the `validate()` function as follows

```
function validate(){
     $array['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
     $array['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
     return $this->db->get_where('user',$array)->num_rows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `$this->load->model('user_model');` *To* `$this->load->model('user_model', 'user');`

and update line `$this->db->get_where('user',$array)->result();` to `return $this->db->get_where('user',$array)->result();` in *User_model* `validate` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you load user model `$this->load->model('user_model');` by default it will assign User_model class object to `user_model` variable in `Login_Controller`. Which you can access as `$this->user_model`.

So when you access `User_model` class method `validate` using `$this->user->validate();` you are getting error `Undefined property: Login_Controller::$user`.

If you want to use `user` variable pass 2nd parameter to load mode method as bellow:
`$this->load->model('user_model', 'user');`